# Discord.js bot: fetch messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've written the next piece of code for a bot I'm making, but I can't figure out what's going wrong:
My code works fine, it fetches messages, but it also triggers the `.catch` from the `channel.messages.fetch(message_id)` call... Which it shouldn't, 'cause it's a successful fetch, there are no errors...
Does anyone have a clue what it could be?

I can provide all my code if required, but I feel like I'm just missing something obvious from the `.then()` statement.

```
var message_fetch = function (
  client,
  channel_id,
  message_id,
  callback,
  event_data) {
  client.channels.fetch(channel_id)
    .then(function (channel) {
      channel.messages.fetch(message_id)
        .then(message => {
          logger.info("message_fetch: message found");
          logger.info(message);
          callback(message, event_data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          logger.error("message_fetch: no message found");
          logger.error(error);
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      logger.error("message_fetch: no channel found");
    });
};
```

Comment: Can you also print the `error` in `.catch()`?

Comment: It prints nothing... thats the weird thing  atleast not when i make it .catch(function (error) {}) im not sure whats going on...

Comment: Didn't `logger.error(error);` print anything?

Comment: Exactly.... its empty :(

Comment: That's strange... It should at least print something like `undefined` or `''`. Can you try using `console.error` to print `error` instead?

Comment: awesome! that seems to work! i now get an error message: `TypeError: message.reactions.get is not a function
    at event_check (/React-o-matic Discord/client_init.js:44:38)
    at /React-o-matic Discord/client_init.js:27:21
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
` i was using logger.error because before console.error wasnt working lol

Comment: this is an error i can finally work with, i knew it was something simple like this! thank you so much! for the record, logger.error only outputted `{"level":"error"}`

Comment: Glad it worked out :)

Comment: is console.error better to use than winston? i was just using winston because its used in the example i used to set up my bot

Comment: It depends on the usage. Logger is useful when you want to set the log level. (e.g. You can log something as debug info, and set the log level to disable them in the final product)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out logger.error (logger being winston) didnt output the error properly. Using console.error was more reliable.
Thanks to sup39